# How to add external features to input images when training GoogLeNet in Caffe?

Tags: python, computer-vision, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I have been using the Caffe framework for fine-tuning the GoogLeNet model using images from my own dataset. I think that I could improve the results if I could add some externally extracted features (like SIFT based or HoG...) to the training images in the training process.

Is there a way I can expand the training dataset to IMAGES + ADDITIONAL FEATURES and train the same model in Caffe using Python?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caffe is not limited to images only. In fact, it can accept (almost) any type of input. You can store your training data in a [`hdf5`](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/) binary file and read it in caffe using `"HDF5Data"` layer. The hdf5 file can store several variables, e.g., `"image"`, `"label"` and addtional `"img_features"`. Thus, your input layer to caffe will look something like:

```
layer {
  name: "input"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "image"
  top: "img_features"
  top: "label"
  ...
}
```

You can use python's [`h5py`](http://www.h5py.org/) python package to create the input `hdf5` files.

Comment: Ok so if I can store the image, external feature vector and label for every image, does this mean that I should have one hdf5 binary file per input image? If it does should I create a lmdb file for the training and validation data afterwards? 

If it does not, then probably there should be one hdf5 file for the whole training collection right?

Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: @GjorgjiStrezoski, please read about `"HDF5Data"` layer: you can have many batches stored in a single `hdf5` file, the layer gets as input a *text* file listing all the `hdf5` files it should read during training/testing.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will do the research regarding HDF5Data... And post my solution as soon as I implement it.